# Unable to Retrieve List Items from SharePoint List Using CAMLQuery in C#

Tags: c#, azure, sharepoint, caml

I am Unable to fetch List Items in SharePoint List using CAMLQuery in C#. I have admin rights and able to fetch Column Names of List but getting List Items count as 0.

Can anyone please help me on this? Below is the Code. Here we are getting value of "collListItem" as 0

```
  cc.Load(cc.Web, p => p.Lists);
            cc.ExecuteQuery();
            var lst = cc.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Tracker List");
            cc.Load(lst.Fields);
            cc.ExecuteQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("\n Columns \n");

            foreach (var item in lst.Fields)
            {
                if (item.Hidden == false)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Title);
                }
            }
            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='false' /></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>5</RowLimit></View>";
            ListItemCollection collListItem = lst.GetItems(camlQuery);
            cc.Load(collListItem);
            cc.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample demo:

```cs
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("http://sp"))
{
    CamlQuery caml = new CamlQuery();
    caml.ViewXml = "<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='false' /></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>5</RowLimit></View>";

    var requestItems = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Test").GetItems(caml);
    clientContext.Load(requestItems);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    foreach(var item in requestItems)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item["Title"]);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.the above code is not working for me. We are using AppId,AppSecret for fetching Items and using same above code which is added by my colleague Sudhanshu. we are following this Link :  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/connect-to-sharepoint-online-site-with-app-only-authentication/  i am using same above code but still no result.What could be the issue ? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply, however its not working for us. We are using app-id and secret for fetching List items and using OfficeDevPnP Nuget for it. We are the owner of SharePoint app and already give FullControl to collection. We are able to get the collection names, Field names of particular List but not ListItems. Sample code snipped for reference.

```
 using OfficeDevPnP.Core;
 using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

using (var clientContext = new AuthenticationManager().GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl, appId, appSecret))
            {

                CamlQuery caml = new CamlQuery();
                caml.ViewXml = "<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='false' /></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>5</RowLimit></View>";

                var requestItems = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName).GetItems(caml);
                clientContext.Load(requestItems);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (var item in requestItems)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item["Title"]);
                }
}
```